# PHP form submit, force CSS reload?

Tags: php, css

I have a PHP form that I need to force a CSS reload once submitted.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to reload the entire page?

Comment: The entire page has the processing script inside it, but when it reloads on submit the CSS is caching.  If I do a ctrl F5 it loads correctly.

Comment: Easiest way to get around this is to append a query to the end of your .css link: mystyle.css?v=1 when the page posts back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of to guarantee that the CSS reloads, is to change the name of the css file.

You could create a rewrite rule that redirects all addresses of type "...mycssfile.css1234" to "...mycssfile.css" and in your php, add a random 4 digits to the end of your css file location.

Edit: To reflect the comments to this answer, you can do the following:

```
<link rel="STYLESHEET" href="mycssfile.css?r=<?php echo rand(1, 999999); ?>" type="text/css">
```

Which would force the browser to update the css page, since the address to the css file changed, although it will actually link to the same css file.

Comment: My suggestion is that you use the modified time of the CSS instead, maybe using `filemtime` or the last time the form was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via Javascript.

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="cssChange()" action=".....
```

For example cssChange function :

```
     function cssChange() {

         var a = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
         var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
         if(a.getAttribute('rel') == 'css')
             {
                    a.attr('src', 'new-css.css?' + random);
             }

     }
```

And you can define **.newClass** class on your css file.

Comment: What would cssChange() do though? You haven't provided the function.

Comment: I wanted to give an idea to him. There are a lot of javascript funtion for changing css file. I will edit my answer now. Thank you.

Comment: that doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: @Ben, can you check answer again ?

Comment: @Eray. Looks better. Maybe add a random number as query string to the css file to prevent caching too.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason the whole page can't reset? Because if that's okay, then the form could just submit to the page itself, with an `action` of `get`, and the (dropdown|input|radio button) submitted as an argument (something like "css").

When the page loads, PHP can check for the variable:

```
$css = empty($_GET['css']) ? $_GET['css'] : 'default';
```

Then, it can echo the stylesheet's `href` based on that variable:

```
<link href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($css, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>.css" ... />
```